Storing polygon and spatial query on polygon in dynamoDB
With Geo library for dynamoDB, it looks like I can store Points and do spatial query on points efficiently.
1, What if I want to store complex geometries like polygons?
2, What if I want to do query more than just radius and rectangle queries? like I want to see how many polygons are intersecting with a certain geometry that I am concerned with.
3, What if I want to implement this with python (geo library so far is only supported in Java I think).
Similar questions in the past showed that features above are not supported. But I just want to see if there is any update, or some PK+SK designs within dynamoDB can somehow achieve my needs.
Thanks

I suggest using a database with built in geometric support, such as MemoryDB or Postgres on Aurora. The library for DynamoDB is no longer maintained as it's in the archived repo, its not suitable for production applications.
